# How can i show customize filter form on delphi, devexpress table view?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

How can i show  customize filter form on delphi, on my own button click..

[image: example form]

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure ShowCustomFilters(AView: TcxGridTableView);
begin
  AView.Filtering.RunCustomizeDialog;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OnFilterDialogShow event handler in order to show a custom filter form instead of default filter form.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1FilterDialogShow(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  //here you can show your custom filter form
  //...

  //setting ADone to True makes sure the default filter form isn't shown
  ADone := True;
end;
```